# PhpStorm, xDebug, sshfs - удаленный дебаг

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

Прокинул тунель до серверного xdebug, подмонтировал удаленный сервер на локальную машину через sshfs. И все бы ничего, но не могу настроить проект или создать. Если выбираю настройку "удаленный веб-сервер, файлы по sftp", то он создает проект, потом висит минут 10, и в итоге начинает зачем то копировать файлы с сервера на локальную машину.

Если выбираю веб-сервер локальный, то вобще все грустно, значка дебага нет, хотя настройки php debug сделаны.

Если выбираю что файлы хранятся локально, а веб сервер настроить потом, то вобще все грустно.

Толкового мануала найти не могу. Помогите плз.